# Evaluate and prove the limit at negative infinity

Tags: calculus

Find $$\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x)$$
where $f(x)=\frac{x^2+1}{x-2}$ and prove your result.

Not sure how to work with negative infinity, please help

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Rewrite the limit using $y=-x$; you'll have 
$$
\lim_{y \rightarrow \infty} -\frac{y^2+1}{y+2}
$$
which can be written as 
$$
-\lim_{y \rightarrow \infty} \frac{y^2-4}{y+2} + \frac{5}{y+2} \\
= -\lim_{y \rightarrow \infty} y-2 + \frac{5}{y+2} 
$$ 
Can you see what the limit is now?

Answer (score 0):

Prove by definition,

Given $M>0$, we aim to find $n\in\mathbb{N}$, s.t. $\forall x<-n$,$\frac{x^2+1}{x-2}<-M$

Note $x^2+1>x^2-4>0,$ if $x<-2$, Hence we pick $n\in\mathbb{N}$,s.t. $n\ge\max(M+2,3)$, then $\forall x<-n$, we have $x\leq-3, x\leq -M-2$ thus

$$\frac{x^2+1}{x-2}<\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}=x+2<-M$$